# What is the value of $K$ in Talagrand's inequality?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, inequality, product-space

In a [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220050108) by Talagrand, the following theorem is proved.

> **Theorem 1.4.** There exists a number $K$ with the following property. Consider
>   $n$ independent random variables $X_i$ valued in a measurable space $\Omega$. Consider a (countable) class $\mathcal{F}$ of measurable functions on $\Omega$. Consider the random variable $Z =\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sum_{i \leq n} f(X_i)$. Consider
>   $$
> U = \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \|f\|_\infty\quad  \text{ and }\quad V = \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \sum_{i \leq n} f(X_i)^2\right]
> $$
>   Then for each $t > 0$, we have
>   $$
> P(\left|Z - \mathbb{E}[Z]\right| \geq t) \leq K \cdot \mathsf{exp}\left(-\frac{t}{KU}\log\left(1 + \frac{tU}{V}\right)\right) 
> $$

**My Question.** What is the exact value of $K$? I need to use that inequality but since I am not familiar with measure theory, some derivations in the paper are hard for me to understand and I cannot find the value of $K$ by myself.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with this to answer, but because LHS and RHS are both expressions in $t$ it would not surprise me if only the *existence* of $K$ is an issue here, and not so much how $K$ looks like. Good chance that any expression for $K$ is hard to get (if not completely unreachable). I hope for you that I am wrong.